# Problems untarring files with long names in linux

Tags: linux, windows, sed, tar

Coming from windows, via tar file generated with 7z. I am having trouble with some long file names:

```
tar: xxxxxxx: Cannot open: File name too long
```

It seems Linux (or tar?) has a 256 character limit for filenames. Fair enough. I am trying to limit the length using the `--xform` option:

```
tar -x --xform 's/^\(.\{200\}\).*/\1/' -f japanese.tar
```

But this does not work. The sed expression is working though:

```
$ echo whateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever | sed -e 's/^\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/'
whateverwh
```

Is the sed expression not supported by tar? Any other way to shorten the names?

Comment: Just after posting this something occurred to me: maybe I do not need to specify `s`? I do. Then I tried something else: make the length of the string really short, 20 instead of 200, and it worked. It seems the japanese characters in my filenames are taking up two (or more bytes), so the real length is actually more than 256 bytes even after reducing it to 200 characters.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: that is exactly what `--xform` is designed for: to reduce (or in general terms, change) the name of the file prior creation. No need for another tool. Just the length was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You excluded file extension in your expression. Could you try this;

```
tar -x --xform 's/^\(.\{200\}\).*\(\.[^.]*\)/\1\2/' -f japanese.tar
```

eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ echo whateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever.txt | sed -e 's/^\(.\{10\}\).*/\1/'
whateverwh
user@host:/tmp/test$ echo whateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever.txt | sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\).*\(\.[^.]*\)/\1\2/'
whateverwh.txt
```